# Can I finish both sides of the Dawnguard DLC

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I want to know if I can become a vampire through Serena or her father and then at a later time cure vampirism and then go through the Dawnguard quest line? I am a bit of a hoarder and want to collect all of the items offered in both quest lines.  Or will I miss out on certain items or quests?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to complete both sides is to reload and play the DLC differently.

Comment: ...  Also if this is not possible, can I visit the locations of both sides of the questlines to obtain the unique items offered in each questline no matter which side I choose?

Comment: You might have to use mods if you are on pc, PS4, or Xbox One.

Comment: Yeah, I am on PS3 and don't really like using mods like that on PC even until I have completed a game as it was written..  I do use in game glitches, only things that are there without adjusting the programing.  Once I have beaten a game fairly with what is available then MOD AWAY lol.

Comment: @Jason Aller  Thank you for editing my question, my typo made it a bit confusing, appreciates you :)

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly i did side with the vampires initially going through the quest-line, however you get multiple options to switch sides in between (right up until the end).
I switched sides after becoming a vampire and played as dawnguard and then switched again. In a single play-through you might get a bit of both sides but you'll definitely miss out on things.

P.S  getting a cure for vampirism is a separate quest independent from dawnguard.